# Excel for Mac 2011 - Conditional Format - Look inside formula for sheet reference

Tags: conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2011

I would like to use conditional formatting to locate all cells on a large sheet (Sheet 1) that have a reference to another sheet (Sheet 2) within a formula in a cell on Sheet 1. I was hoping I could look inside the formula for the name of Sheet 2 and conditionally format the cell if it has a reference to Sheet 2. Possible?